# Where does Three.js set the default shaders for materials?

Tags: javascript, three.js, shader

I'm trying to track down where exactly the fragment and vertex shaders are being set after creating a Three.js material, with little luck. Using the ParticleSystemMaterial, I have

```js
material = new THREE.ParticleSystemMaterial();
console.log(material);
```

Looking at the developer console in Firefox, I can see `fragmentShader` and `vertexShader` both set with default values:

[image: Object Properties from Browser Console]

However, I'm curious where these values are coming from. Tracing back from the source code from [ParticleSystemMaterial.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/materials/ParticleSystemMaterial.js) and [Material.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/materials/Material.js), I don't see anything explicitly stating where these shaders are set. I'm assuming they're being pulled at some point from [ShaderLib.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/renderers/shaders/ShaderLib.js), but nothing in either source codes seems to indicate this being done at all.

Does anyone have any idea about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The shader for `ParticleSystemMaterial` is `THREE.ShaderLib[ 'particle_basic' ]`, and it can be found in the source files `ShaderLib.js` and `ShaderChunk.js`.

The material-to-shader assignments can be found in the method `WebGLRenderer.initMaterial()` in `WebGLRenderer.js`.

three.js. r.67

Note: `PaticleSystem` is being renamed to `PointCloud`, and `PaticleSystemMaterial` is being renamed to `PointCloudMaterial` in r.68dev.

Comment: Interesting. When does initMaterial() get called? From what I see, it doesn't seem to happen during construction of a Material, yet it seems to already have been called the moment the Material is constructed and then printed via console.log().

Comment: You can track the calling tree by setting break points in the debugger.